# How can I use a static (ish) URL for the featured image for a post?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to store all my featured images on S3, and then use imgix transforms to display them. So basically, instead of Wordpress inserting:

`http://www.foodiefun.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/no-sandwich-lunch-ideas1.jpg`

whenever it displays that featured post, I want it to use:

`http://foodiefun.imgix.net/featured/no-sandwich-lunch-ideas.jpg?fit=fill&bg=f9f9f9&w=400&h=600`

It's probably worth noting that */no-sandwhich-lunch-ideas* is the URL of the post.

Anybody have any tips? It seems like this would be easy to do, but Google failed me.

Comment: You could parse the attachment object and come up with the url by piecing it together using the known domain and path with the image name, but that seems a bit flimsy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Using the Genesis framework, you can do this, adapted from http://dreamwhisperdesigns.com/genesis-tutorials/genesis-default-thumbnails/

```
/**
 * Default Image
 *
 * @author Jen Baumann
 * @link http://dreamwhisperdesigns.com/?p=429
 */
add_filter('genesis_get_image', 'dream_default_image', 10, 2);
function dream_default_image($output, $args) {
    global $post;
    $slug = $post->post_name;
    $thumbnail = 'http://foodiefun.imgix.net/featured/'.$slug.'.jpg?fit=fill&bg=f9f9f9&w=400&h=600';

    switch($args['format']) {

        case 'html' :
            return '<img src="'.$thumbnail.'" class="alignleft post-image" alt="'. get_the_title($post->ID) .'" />';
            break;
        case 'url' :
            return $thumbnail;
            break;
        default :
            return $output;
            break;
    }
}
```